# Find a file in Cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, command, cygwin

I use `find -name "nametofind"` in `cygwin` to search for a file, but it does not give me any result, even when the file I want to search exists in the current directory. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `find . -name nametofind`

Comment: i did that also ,but no result ..

Comment: `find . -iname '*nametofind*'`?

Comment: @YOU: What do you get when you do: `echo *nametofind*|cat -vte`

Comment: Thanks devnull ,anubhava ,both solutions get the result .

Comment: @devnull, I incorporated your comment into my answer, but if you prefer to write your own answer, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment mentioned more succinctly, you need to tell `find` which directory you want to search. If you it is the current directory, you should use `.`.

```
find . -name "nametofind"
```

It appears that the OP was trying to either match a partial file name or a file name with a different case. As @devnull mentioned in his comment, the correct solution for either case is to use the following.

```
find . -iname '*nametofind*'
```

Comment: i did it already ,but nothing happen ,any suggestion else ,thanks

Comment: @YOU, You need to make sure you are invoking the `cygwin` version of find, not the Windows version.

Comment: `which find` and this is the result `/usr/bin/find`

Comment: @YOU, See the update. Also, if you are trying to match a partial name, then devnull's comment will help you.

Comment: Thanks @merlin2011 ,devnull and anubhava 's comments did the job

Comment: and `/usr/bin/find . -name "nametofind"` still got no result.